# How to make a memory dump in .net?

Tags: .net, memory, trace, dump, memory-dump

How do you obtain a memory dump from a given memory address in the format:

```
  Address   |           Hexadecimal representation              | ASCII representation
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0x637132687 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   45 21 65 78 32 F5 12 6C |  ....... ahsnfdas
0x637132703 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   45 21 65 78 32 F5 12 6C |  ....... ahsnfdas
0x637132719 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   45 21 65 78 32 F5 12 6C |  ....... ahsnfdas
0x637132735 | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   45 21 65 78 32 F5 12 6C |  ....... ahsnfdas
```

Do you know any API/framework/tool for the work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need Marshal.CopyMemory() and [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426190/how-to-read-file-binary-in-c/2426258#2426258).  P/Invoking VirtualQueryEx() to ensure the memory addresses are valid would be a good idea to avoid exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I'm going to take this approach : ) +1

Answer (score 1):

It can certainly be done using WinDbg. Honestly, I'm not a wizard using it but Tess Ferrandez from Microsoft is and has an [excellent](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/) blog about using WinDbg to debug .NET applications.

It seems you just want to browse a normal memory dump, that should be pretty straightforward. If you want to examine anything further (with regards to .net) you should use the SOS extensions for WinDbg.

Comment: Thank you Johannes! nice link +1