# Trying to Read Strings from a Binary File

Tags: c#, string, binaryfiles, msdn

Here is a simple program I made just trying to write a couple variables to a binary file, and then reading it back.

I'm trying to figure out how to read a string from a binary file. It wrote it correctly. But every time I try to read it(In this example it's 4 bytes), the result comes out really weird, which throws everything off. b = "jump", yet no matter how I try to read and convert, the end result turns out to something weird. And then variable b, which is read after it, also turns out weird.

**What is the proper way to read a string from a binary file?** All my strings are going to be fixed length anyways, 15 characters. Is there a way to do it without converting to a char array?

I also tried the .ReadCharArrays() method, and then toString(), and I'm still not reading the correct variables.

```
string path = ".//..//..//..//";

FileStream mfs = new FileStream(path + "test.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(mfs);
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(mfs);

short a = 2;
short b = 3;
string c = "JUMP";
bw.Write(a);
bw.Write(c);
bw.Write(b);

Console.WriteLine("Done writing to binary file");
br.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //Apprantly you have to seek to beginning

a = br.ReadInt16();
c = br.ReadBytes(4).toString();
b = br.ReadInt16();

Console.WriteLine(""+a);
Console.WriteLine(""+c);
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("" +b);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426190/how-to-read-file-binary-in-c

Answer (score 2):

What makes you think that "JUMP" occupies 4 bytes?

> BinaryWriter.Write(string):
>
> Writes a length-prefixed string to this stream in the current encoding of the BinaryWriter,

Comment: This is really  more of a comment, isn't it?

Comment: Actually, it's a pointer to the answer. I don't like to spoonfeed. I was going to add that br.ReadString is the right api, but as @500 has done so already there's little point.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on how many bytes one string would be though. I thought each character in the string is essentially 1 byte, so an 8 char string would be 8 bytes, etc.

Comment: That might hold true for single byte encoding such as ascii. It's not the case for many chars in other encodings though. In this case with UTF8, it probably is 4 bytes... but what about the length prefix? you forgot about that. By adding a length field, it means that you don't have to know the length of the string before you read it with BR.ReadString. Got it?

Comment: @user2066820, as far as I remember the string is written as is variable length integer for length followed by properly encoded characters (default UTF8), so in case of "JUMP" it should be 5 bytes.

Comment: Apparently, the length field described in the docs as utf7 encoded unsigned integer is actually LEB128: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LEB128

Answer (score 2):

You should use BinaryReader.ReadString() to read the string back in - ReadBytes reads an array of bytes and by default strings are unicode in .NET.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know .ReadString() existed for C#.

Comment: +1. @user2066820, consider using Visual Studio to edit CS files and  paying attention to intellisence suggestions - it should have shown you ReadString as an option when you've typed "br.Read".

Answer (score 2):

`BinaryReader.ReadString()`. I just tested your code and it appears to work fine:

```
a = br.ReadInt16();
string d = br.ReadString(); // store in another variable just to be sure..
b = br.ReadInt16();

Console.WriteLine("" + a);
Console.WriteLine("" + d); // JUMP
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("" + b);
```

Comment: Yea it did work! Now just need to figure out how many bytes it would be. A short is 2 bytes. This is important because later I will be doing Direct Address(in a bigger project of course).

Comment: @user2066820 Do you really need to invent a new binary format? It might be better for you to look at binary serialization as an alternative.