# Converting bytes[] to literal string

Tags: c#

I have a problem in my C# program. I am currently developing a gateway (both TCP and UDP protocols), and have to log the traffic to a file. I got some test data to try my gateway with. Example data: ASYRE\x00\x00\x01.

My program should log this into a file, and here comes my problem: When logging to the file (or writing it onto the Console) i get ASYRE, and the special \x00\x00\x01 characters will be decoded in the file, however, i have to log them as they came in, so when logging they should be "ASYRE\x00\x00\x01".

I tried using `Encoding.Default.GetString()`, `Convert.ToString()`, `Parse` and even `Regex`, but I don't know how to get it to be logged correctly.

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311165/how-do-you-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hexadecimal-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: Hi, could you show how you save and read data? If you use text editors to see what data is being written they probably will not display raw bytes correctly. Is the output binary data - then you'd need to _read_ it as binary.

Comment: The data comes in through the network from a client written in Python, where it is like this: 
msg1 = b'ASYRE\x00\x00\x01'

In the Python program's logger there is no problem to log it as it goes out: 127.0.0.1:53760 -> 127.0.0.1:1002 (8b) b'ASYRE\x00\x00\x01' (from the Python log file)

I recieve the program on in my C# program through sockets:
`int len;
len = stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
byte[] msg = new byte[len];
Array.Copy(message, msg, len);`

Comment: Consider displaying the bytes [in hex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2426258/17034).

Comment: what happens when someone sends `Renée` ?  Will it output `Renée` or will it output `Ren\xc3\xa9e`  (or something else...) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a string *Dump*, which you can implement with a help of *Linq*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static string Dump(string value) {
  if (null == value)
    return "[null]";

  return string.Concat(value.Select(c =>
      c < ' ' ? $"\\x{(int)c:x2}"
    : char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.Format ? $"\\u{(int)c:x4}"
    : c.ToString()));
}
```

If you want a solution without *Linq*, have a look at `StringBuilder`:

```
private static string Dump(string value) {
  if (null == value)
    return "[null]";

  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  foreach(char c in value) 
    if (c < ' ')
      sb.Append($"\\x{(int)c:x2}");
    else if (char.GetUnicodeCategory(c) == UnicodeCategory.Format) 
      sb.Append($"\\u{(int)c:x4}");
    else
      sb.Append(c);

  return sb.ToString(); 
}
```

**Demo:**

```
Console.Write(Dump("ASYRE\x00\x00\x01"));
```

**Outcome:**

```
ASYRE\x00\x00\x01
```

Answer (score 1):

Something short that assumes you're working with ASCII

```
byte[] input = { 65, 83, 89, 82, 69, 0, 0, 1 };
var output = string.Concat(input.Select(b => b < 32 ? $"\\x{b:X02}" : Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] {b})));
System.Console.WriteLine(output);
```

prints `ASYRE\x00\x00\x01`